# How to filter special characters in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-class-based-views, django-template-filters

I am trying to display ValuesQuerySet list to drop down list in django template page. I jus to filter special characters while displaying in drop down. I tried autoescape syntax but it doesn't work. Is anyother way to do this.

in views.py:

```
 email_accounts = EmailAccount.objects.filter(user__user=self.request.user).values()
 form.fields['account'].queryset = email_accounts.values_list('a_email')
```

Here the value should like [{'a_email': u'xx@gmail.com'}, {'a_email': u'yy@gmail.com'}, {'a_email': u'zzz@gmail.com'}].

In template page

```
  {{ form.account }}
```

So it displayed like below in drop down list

```
 (u'xx@gmail.com')
 (u'yy@gmail.com')
 (u'zz@gmail.com')
```

I need to remove (u') those special chars when displaying in to drop down list. How to do that? any one suggest me.

Comment: What exactly do you mean, "filter"? What are you trying to do? What is your current output, and what output are you expecting? What does your template look like now?

Comment: in drop down list it look like this (u'xxxxx@gmail.com'). I jus want to remove (u'') those special chars. It's jus to look xxxxx@gmail.com

Comment: Well, that is a completely separate issue, which has nothing to do with "special characters". You have a list of tuples, when you should have a plain list. You need to show how you are generating that list, and how you are outputting it in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a ValuesQueryset at all here. The `queryset` parameter for a ModelChoiceField expects, not surprisingly, a standard queryset.

```
email_accounts = EmailAccount.objects.filter(user__user=self.request.user)
form.fields['account'].queryset = email_accounts
```